# How to convert a spatial Oracle LOB object type to a Geodataframe listlike geometry object column

Tags: python, pycharm, geometry-data-type, geodataframe, cx-oracle

I have in my dataframe one column with `cx_Oracle.LOB` object [2D polygon type], made with a `SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY SQL` function and I want to create a geodataframe, and set my geometry column the geometry returned from the `SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY` function to a valid geodataframe listlike geometry.

The Geodataframe function return error when i set the geometry column with the `WKTGEOMETRY` made with `SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY` function. I work with PyCharm application.

my dataframe:

```
dfparc = pd.DataFrame(dfparc.values, columns=['PAR_ID', 'PAR_NUM', 'geometry', 'AREA_HA', 'DCF'])

print(type(dfparc.geometry[0]))

class 'cx_Oracle.LOB'>

print(dfparc.geometry[0])

POLYGON ((225215.22 411994.91, 225214.02 411912.51, 225339.62 411916.91, 225339.62 411995.31, 225279.22 411995.31, 225215.22 411994.91))
```

My Geodataframe:

```
geoparc = gp.GeoDataFrame(dfparc, crs=102160, geometry=dfparc.geometry)

returned errors:

...Python35-32\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geodataframe.py", line 50, in __init__
     self.set_geometry(geometry, inplace=True)
...Python35-32\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geodataframe.py", line 149, in set_geometry
    raise TypeError("Input geometry column must contain valid geometry objects.") TypeError: Input geometry column must contain valid geometry objects.
```

I suppose the problem could be in the type of object returned from SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY function that is not available for geodataframe geometry data type.

Comment: We might need to see your code populating dfparc with the SQL used.  As I don't have the environment to test, my guess is converting the CLOB to a string (VARCHAR) might help.  You can do this in the SQL statement or with Python.

Comment: here is my sql statement made to a oracle spatial (client profile): queryparcel = "select PAR_ID, PAR_NUM, SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY(PAR_POLIGONO) as geometry, round(par_area/10000,3) as AREA_HA, DCF from sig_parcela_vw where PAR_NUM IN ('4117654001', '4126925016')"

Comment: then i set the SQL result to cursor: result = cursor.execute(queryparcel)
cursor.arraysize = 500

Comment: then i create a dataframe with the cursor: dfparc = pd.DataFrame(result)

Comment: after that i set the Dataframe columns names: dfparc = pd.DataFrame(dfparc.values, columns=['PAR_ID', 'PAR_NUM', 'geometry', 'AREA_HA', 'DCF'])

Comment: finally, when i tried to create the Geodataframe with the geometry column data, returns the errors above: geoparc = gp.GeoDataFrame(dfparc, crs=102160, geometry=dfparc.geometry)

Comment: where am i doing wrong?

Comment: Can you update the question instead of adding comments?  It will help others understand what you're doing in the flow of the problem.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hesitate to give this answer as I cannot test it, however, one way to avoid dealing with CLOB data types is to convert the result to VARCHAR2.

From the [help page](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SPATL/sdo_util-from_wktgeometry.htm#SPATL1234) on `SDO_UTIL.FROM_WKTGEOMETRY` (you are calling the TO_ but the usage notes on the FROM_ page reference the TO_):

> You can use the SQL function TO_CHAR to convert the resulting CLOB to VARCHAR2 type.

This would make your SQL look something like:

```
select PAR_ID, PAR_NUM, 
  TO_CHAR(SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY(PAR_POLIGONO)) as geometry, 
  round(par_area/10000,3) as AREA_HA, DCF 
from sig_parcela_vw 
where PAR_NUM IN ('4117654001', '4126925016')
```

Comment: Now i have the BLOB objet converted to VARCHAR. GREAT! Thanks!

Comment: But the geometry column construction in Geodataframe still return the error "TypeError: Input geometry column must contain valid geometry objects."

Comment: Iam triyng to find out where is the problem with the geometry column in Geodataframe.

Comment: @PauloAdão You don't have to accept my answer if it didn't help.  People may not read your question if this answer is accepted.  Feel free to remove the accepted check mark and update your original question.

Comment: Your answer fulfill the object type conversion. That was great!. One step at the time... :)